# Remove the last 3 characters of the string if the string has the same prefix and suffix

Tags: java, string, compare, prefix, suffix

I want to remove the last 3 characters of the string if the string has the same prefix and suffix. eg: the string is `"systemsys"`, it should print `system`. Few inputs I am trying : `incgoogleinc`. Not working for this input

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public  static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = s.nextLine();
    if(str.length() > 3) { 
    if (str.startsWith(str.substring(0, 3)) == (str.substring(str.length()-3, str.length()-1))) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length()-3));    
    } else {
        System.out.println(str);
}}}
```

Not working for different inputs : `mictestingmic`, `comwebsitecom`

Answer (score 2):

```java
if (str.startsWith(str.substring(0, 3)) == (str.substring(str.length()-3, str.length()-1))) {
```

`str.startsWith(str.substring(0, 3))` returns a boolean (which happens to always be true because you're asking if it starts with the beginning of the string, which it always does).

`str.substring(str.length()-3, str.length()-1))`

For "mictestmic", this will return "mi", since `substring()` uses inclusive/exclusive ranges.

Therefore, your `if` statement evaluates to:

```
if (true == "mi") {
```

Instead, simply check if the string starts with the end:

```java
if (str.startsWith(str.substring(str.length()-3))) {
```

Comment: I got this logic now! I would like to know using the above logic isn't a correct way for this types of comparisons?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question

Comment: `substring(str.length()-3, str.length())` can be shortened to `substring(str.length()-3)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are allowed to use regex in your assignment, but it comes in handy here:

```
String input = "mictestingmic";
if (input.matches("(.+).*\\1")) {
    input = input.substring(0, input.length()-3);
}

System.out.println(input);
```

This prints `mictesting`, the last three characters removed, but `mictestingcan` would print the same input, since it does have a matching prefix and suffix.

Comment: The code is working perfect! Thanks. I am still checking if there can be some alternatives for it as a beginner.

Comment: @ShantanuUdasi If input is `"mtestingm"`, the regex will be true, since the string does have the same prefix and suffix, the 1-character string `"m"`, and the code would then remove the last 3, resulting in `"mtesti"`. Is that really what should happen? --- Note that the answer follows the requirements in the question exactly, since the question never stipulates a specific length to the prefix/suffix, but the code in the question implies that prefix/suffix should be 3-character strings. Beware imprecise requirements.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the comment, and I was thinking of this as well when I answered.  If the requirement is for a three-length prefix/suffix, then we can try using the pattern `(.{3}).*\1`

Comment: To combine the `matches` and `substring` calls, use `replaceFirst`, i.e. `input = input.replaceFirst("((.{3}).*)\\2", "$1");`